# Stack Exchange android app crashes a lot

Tags: support, android-app

Stack Exchange android app crashes a lot with no obvious reason 
Is that s common ? Or just in my case 
I am using an android jb4.1.1 device ZTE grand v970m

Using Android app version 1.0.35.

Comment: Are you hitting "Report" on the crash dialog? Further, support questions for the Stack Exchange Android app should be asked on [metase] and tagged with `android-app`. As it stands though, this question really doesn't have enough detail for anyone to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of the app are you using? We automatically get notified of all crashes, and it looks like only 80 crashes total have happened on the newest version, 1.0.38.

Comment: I am using v 1.0.35

Comment: @AhmedGawad please use the Play Store to update to the newest version.